# How to unregister a dll and then register a dll on the same batch file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I unregistered and registered a dll manually by using the following commands in the command prompt.

Unregister:

```
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\RegAsm.exe "C:\Program Files\ABC\foo.dll" /codebase /u
```

Register:

```
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\RegAsm.exe "C:\Program Files\ABC\foo.dll" /codebase
```

So help me using batch commands so that clients can run this batch without knowing how to do it manually

Comment: What part of the interaction needs to be hidden from the user?  Just the running of these two commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A batch file, simply put, is just a long list of command line commands that are executed sequentially. So to make a .bat file with your commands.  Create a text file and name it File.bat and then copy an paste your commands into the file.  Save and you are done.  Note that there are a few differences when working with symbols on the command and then in bat files, but for what you need it is not an issue.

**Example:**

```
:: Hide commands statements
@echo off

:: Unregister
"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\RegAsm.exe" "C:\Program Files\ABC\foo.dll" /codebase /u

:: Register
"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\RegAsm.exe" "C:\Program Files\ABC\foo.dll" /codebase
```

**Great Batch References:**

[`Technet`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772390%28v=ws.10%29.aspx), [`Rob`](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/batchfiles.php), [`SS64`](http://ss64.com/), [`DosTips`](http://www.dostips.com/)